# How to access a container from a Bluemix app?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I've created a container which is listening on port 56789. The container have a private IP 172.xxx.xxx.xxx

I tried to connect from an application that I've deployed in Bluemix but I always get an error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:56789`

I tried to bind a public IP and try to connect doing telnet but I can't connect either

The docker container has an application that opens a socket in the port 56789

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to reach an IBM Container from a Bluemix application using the private container IP, since the environments are in different networks.

You have to assign a public IP to your IBM container as you are doing, but also your application in the container needs to run in an open port.

The IBM container has a firewall and it whitelists the open ports, 56789 is not in the list, hence you cannot even telnet to the container using this port.

If you can use a random port try port 50000 for your test.

For security reasons the list of open ports is not externally documented - if you need a particular port to be opened please open a ticket with Bluemix support:

http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport

Comment: If I can't open a port that I need to run my container and I can't use the private IP, how can I use the Bluemix service for create my apps?

Comment: Like I said in my answer if the port you need is not open yet you can open a ticket with support and request it to be opened. Port 56789 is not open.